# admin-on-rest feed with state record

Tags: reactjs, admin-on-rest, react-admin

I have a DisabledInput like

```
<DisabledInput source="values" />
```

But I want to feed this field with a state variable. Because this state variable can change with the user interaction. More precisely, On the page, there is a listbox and when the user add a new value to this listbox, the "values" state variable changes like

"item1, item2, item3..." and I want to give this state variable as data to the DisabledInput

```
this.state.values
```

I don't know how to do that. Maybe there is a way like as follows but I couldn't do that

```
<DisabledInput source="values" record={this.state.values} />
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Can you make a codesandbox showing what you tried already ?

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/nno0kon4qm

The file that I mention in the post is ListEditor.js

Comment: Can you please make it usable ?

Comment: My REST Api is working on my local, so I couldn't do that, I've solved this problem with another way. Thank you

Comment: Can you share your solution ?

Comment: I used ArrayInput as follows.
I didn't realized this component before.


{this.state.listEditorVisible ?

      <ArrayInput source='values'>
       <SimpleFormIterator>
        <TextInput source='name' />
       </SimpleFormIterator>
      </ArrayInput>
      :
      null}

Comment: You should put that example as the solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

I used ArrayInput as follows. 
I didn't realized this component before.

```
<SelectInput source='type'
            choices={[
                { name: 'String', id: 'string' },
                { name: 'Enum', id: 'enum' },
                { name: 'Decimal', id: 'decimal' }
            ]}
            onChange={event => {
                const type = Object.values(event).slice(0, -1).join('');
                this.setState({
                    listEditorVisible: type === 'enum',
                    regexEditorVisible: type === 'string',
                    decimalEditorVisible: type === 'decimal'
                });
            }}
/>
{this.state.listEditorVisible ?
    <ArrayInput source='values'>
        <SimpleFormIterator>
            <TextInput source='name' />
        </SimpleFormIterator>
    </ArrayInput>
    :
    null}
{this.state.decimalEditorVisible ?
    <div>
        <NumberInput source="min" /><br />
        <NumberInput source="max" /><br />
        <NumberInput source="res" /><br />
        <TextInput source="unit" />
    </div>
    :
    null}
```